# not able to generate app for sencha touch s

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have been searching long but still so many solutions and so many confusions but i am still not be able to generate sencha touch app

I have installed `SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3` and `Sencha Cmd 3.1.1.274`

here is `PATH`

> /Users/jhon/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274:/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

When i fire command `sencha which` i can see following path

```
Sencha Cmd v3.1.1.274
/Users/john/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274/
```

and when i try to generate my app using following command

```
sencha generate app myapp /Library/WebServer/Documents/myapp
```

i am getting following error

```
Sencha Cmd v3.1.1.274
[INF] Workspace does not have framework null at /Library/WebServer/Documents ... copying
[ERR] Failed to determine framework name.  Please ensure this command was issued from either a framework or application directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a path issue, in my box if I use an absolute path, it starts from where the bin cmd is located:

```
ng@ng-laptop-kv:~$ sencha generate app MyAPP /myapppp
Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF] -before-generate-workspace:
[INF] init-properties:
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF] init:
[INF] generate-workspace-impl:
[INF]      [echo] generating into /myapppp from /home/ng/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/templates/workspace
[ERR] Directory /myapppp/packages creation was not successful for an unknown reason
```

..and it works with a relative path

Answer (score 0):

you should use this command

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/SDK generate app MyApp /path/to/MyApp
```

/path/to/SDK is where you copied your sencha sdk files

Answer (score 0):

I solved the installation several errors sencha changing the following: 
Two VERY IMPORTANT files:

/Users/sencha/.bashrc 
/Users/sencha/.bash_profile

Hello friends, 
I solved the installation several errors sencha changing the following: 
Two VERY IMPORTANT files:

My Personal install folder:

```
/Sancha
```

Default installation location:

```
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/
```

Take a look:

nano /Users/sencha/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH


export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"


export PATH=/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH


export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"
#
export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH


export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"


SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/
#
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH=/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_4_0_0="/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"
#
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

nano /Users/sencha/.bashrc

```
export PATH=/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH


export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/sencha/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"


export PATH=/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH
#
export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Sencha/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"


export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH


export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"


SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/
#
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH=/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_4_0_0="/Users/admin/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84"
#
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/command:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/jsbuilder:$PATH
#export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta/appbuilder:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I had downloaded zipped GPL version of extJS and extracted in ext-6.0.1-gpl folder. The sdk folder is one folder inside, so the actual path is ext-6.0.1-gpl\ext-6.0.1 - This folder contains fodlers like .sencha, build, classic, etc. I noticed that after few commands this folder was corrupted and contained just error log. So I again extracted the original GPL version and checked to see extracted files looked ok. Then I executed the generate command.
So the key is to check if your sdk folder contains necessary files/folders or its corrupted. If not, the cd to sdk directory and run the command, it should work just :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look first below **video**. This video explains how we can set up app in Ext JS. You have to use **Sencha touch framework** (in video Ext js framework has been used), other steps are same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXMlnS_26CQ